# Want to use glyph getting error in a C# WinUI 3 Desktop program

Tags: c#, desktop, winui-3, winui, glyph-substitution

I am attempting to use font 'Segoe MDL2 Assets' glyphs in a c# WinUI desktop program. Microsoft docs specify this:

*You can assign a value from the Symbol enumeration, or a Unicode string that references a glyph in the Segoe MDL2 Assets font.
You can use the Character Map application that comes with Windows to browse the font's glyphs and find their Unicode values. Then, use the format "&#x/(UNICODE);" in XAML.*

I selected the 'check mark' as a test: U+E001

[image]

```
<Button x:Name="buttonGlyph" ToolTipService.ToolTip="delete" BorderBrush="Transparent" >&#x/U+E001;</Button>
```

The line won't compile, I get the error 'Invalid character in hexadecimal character entity...'

Have I entered &#x/U+E001; incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `&#xe001`. But your code  sample is not complete, you should show the code referencing the font. You must add it as a resource or at the very least specify the `FontFamily` property of a `TextBlock` in the button.

Comment: Thank you NWoodsman, that worked!  Thank you for showing me how to enter the unicode value properly.  I did have to specify the FontFamily in the control, I did not need to add it as a resource. Thank you again so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Button>
    <Button.Content>
        <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets">&#xe001</TextBlock>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Or a cleaner way:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Content>
        <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE001;"/>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

I don't have the font to properly specify the name, so I guessed at it. If the font is installed on your system and you type the name correctly in the `FontFamily` attribute, this should resolve.